# Dynamically tile a tensor depending on the batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 1D tensor a that I want to stack/pack/tile into a 2D tensor like `y=[a, a, a]`. If I knew how many times I wanted it repeated, I could use `tf.tile` along with `reshape`.

But I don't because the size is dependent on the batch size. The placeholder value is `None` which isn't a valid input. I know for `tf.slice` one can input `-1` and let tensorflow figure it out, but I don't see how tensorflow could infer the correct size. I do have a tensor `x` that would be equal in shape to `y`, but I don't see a `tile_like` function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806136/tensorflow-shape-of-a-tiled-tensor?rq=1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `tf.shape` to find out the runtime shape of a tensor, and use it as the basis for the argument to `tf.tile`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])

y = tf.tile([2, 3], tf.shape(x)[0:1])

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: np.zeros([11, 3])}))
```

I verified this code works with the Tensorflow 1.0 release candidiate. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Peter Hawkins for your great answer. In many cases, an additional reshape step is required in order to add the batch_size as the first dimension. I have added an optional extra step that reshapes the tensor:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_dependent_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])
other_tensor = tf.constant([2, 3])

y = tf.tile(other_tensor, tf.shape(batch_dependent_tensor)[0:1])

# Reshaping the y tensor by adding the batch_size as the first dimension
new_shape = tf.concat([tf.shape(batch_dependent_tensor)[0:1], tf.shape(other_tensor)[0:1]], axis=0)
y_reshaped = tf.reshape(y, new_shape)

sess = tf.Session()
y_val, y_reshaped_val = sess.run([y, y_reshaped], feed_dict={batch_dependent_tensor: np.zeros([11, 3])})
print("y_val has shape %s, and value: %s" %(y_val.shape, y_val))
print("y_reshaped_val has shape %s, and value: %s" %(y_reshaped_val.shape, y_reshaped_val))

"""
# print output:

y_val has shape (22,), and value: [2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3]
y_reshaped_val has shape (11, 2), and value: [[2 3]
 [2 3]
 [2 3]
 [2 3]
 [2 3]
 [2 3]
 [2 3]
 [2 3]
 [2 3]
 [2 3]
 [2 3]]
"""
```

Please note that if other_tensor has a rank > 1 (it is a matrix or a tensor with higher dimension) some modifications to the code are required.